# PIC32MX UART error using UART 5

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I am using PIC32MX Clicker (PIC32MX534F064H microcontroller) for transmitting data through UART and receiving the same on PC using a USB to serial converter at baudrate 115200.

When I try to send the data through PIC32 and read on my PC, I recieved data but, which are different. Please see below for code snippets. It would be great if anyone could suggest me what to modify to get the uart working. Thanks

```
#define GetSystemClock()      (80000000ul)
#define GetPeripheralClock()  (GetSystemClock()/(1 << OSCCONbits.PBDIV))
#define GetInstructionClock() (GetSystemClock())

void initSerial(){
UARTConfigure(UART5,UART_ENABLE_PINS_TX_RX_ONLY);
 UARTSetFifoMode(UART5, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL
     | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);
 UARTSetLineControl(UART5, UART_DATA_SIZE_8_BITS | UART_PARITY_NONE |  UART_STOP_BITS_1);
UARTSetDataRate(UART5, GetPeripheralClock(), 115200);
UARTEnable(UART5, UART_ENABLE_FLAGS(UART_PERIPHERAL | UART_RX | UART_TX));
}


void writeSerial(uint8_t c){
while(!UARTTransmitterIsReady(UART5));
UARTSendDataByte(UART5, c);
while(!UARTTransmissionHasCompleted(UART5));
}
```

Comment: "I recieved data but, which are different" - **different HOW**?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your serial port settings on your terminal are the same as the PIC?

Comment: Have you really got your chip running at 80MHz? What config bits did you set, and what clock source do you have on that board?

Answer (score 0):

"Different answer"- maybe they are represented as ASCII values on the PC.
Check if the baud rate of the PIC is 115200 by probing the signal when data is sent.
Make sure that same parity and stop bits are set at the PIC and PC